# Command Prompt being Illogical? Want to add numbers using Rename

Tags: windows, command-line, rename, batch-rename

My camera only numbers photos using 4 digits, but I am now well into the 5 digit realm. So for thousands of photos, I would like to add a fifth digit. E.g. rename IMG_2450 to IMG_12450.

I did this before about a year ago using Command Prompt, but I'm having trouble replicating those results today.

I tried: ren IMG_*.jpg IMG_1*.jpg
and variations like: ren IMG_????.jpg IMG_1????.jpg

But what ends up happening is that instead of adding the number 1, command prompt ends up replacing the first character of the existing string of numbers.

So, IMG_2450 becomes IMG_1450 rather than IMG_12450.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need. Run the following command:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %a in ('dir /b img_*.jpg') do @echo ren "%a_%b" "%a_1%b"
```

If you're happy with the output, delete the `@echo` and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> FOR %v IN (IMG_*.jpg) DO REN %v 1%v

Source: http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/DOS7/z-ren1.html

Comment: Pretty sure last time I saw lfnfor was back in Win9x, and I doubt the OP's still using that.

Comment: @Karan sorry, copied verbatim...

Comment: Command's still incorrect BTW; try it and see where the 1 ends up.

Comment: Well, that might work if Michael is using Windows 95, 98, or Me, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM) says that those are the only versions of Windows that support the `LFNFOR` command.  You might want to think twice before quoting from a page that refers to the Windows Command Prompt as “Dos” and refers to quotes as “inverted commas”.